# Should Asynctask be paused when the user clicks home button

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I had situation while my Asyctask is running.

User clicks home button while AsyncTask is running . 
Should AsyncTask be allowed to run when the app is in background or should it be paused and resumed when the app comes foreground .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. What is the AsyncTask doing?

If it is synchronizing data up to a server, it should probably be left alone. Is the async task doing something that will always have to be redone in onResume()? Cancel it.

If it is loading data, it could go either way. Will the activity/fragment force a reload of the data in onResume() or will it allow the loader (you are using async loaders I hope) to fill in the data it loaded in the background when the user was temporarily switched to the background?

You have to ask yourself, is this task running something expensive (resource-wise) that won't be helpful when not in the foreground?

Also keep in mind, the OS could cancel the task itself on its own too. As long as you're cleaning up resources appropriately, handling cancellations and null activities in callbacks appropriately, leaving it running won't be the end of the world.